# Multiple bootstrap carousel, single page, dynamic ids (via ngFor) - how to add prev/next buttons

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, carousel, ngfor

I am designing a mock up car sale website. I have an ngFor loop creating my Cards, which display a carousel and data about each car.

The problem I am facing currently is that every carousel prev/next button will only control the first carousel generated due to the href corresponding to the first ID.

I am unsure how to pass the dynamically generated carousel ID into the href to navigate slides

I would highly appreciate an explanation as to where I am going wrong or a link to somewhere I can further my knowledge.

I have tried:

- inserting {{Car.id}} into href (no worky - understandably why)
- swapping href for [href] i.e [href]="Car.id"

^ results in a page reload to /Car.id (eg /12)

also tried prepending # -> [href]="'#' + Car.id"

core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '17'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '17'

- swapping href for ng-href i.e ng-href="{{Car.id}}"

```
    <div *ngFor="let Car of carArray; let i = index" class="card">
      <div id="{{Car.id}}" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
        <div class="carousel-inner">


          <div *ngFor="let Car of carArray; let isFirst = first" [class.active]="isFirst" class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{Car.img}}" alt="{{Car.img}}">
          </div>
        </div>



        <a class="carousel-control-prev" [href]="Car.id" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#id1" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
```

Can't bind to 'ng-href' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("

```
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" [ERROR ->]ng-href="{{Car.id}}" role="button" data-slide="prev">
```

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-carousel?

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for this suggestion! I think I will resort to this if I need to, Just had a fiddle in stackblitz and it seems useful.

edit: enter sends message apparently - But it doesn't solve what I am trying to figure out unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it after a lot more googling!

Had to remove the `<a>` tags and replace with `<span>` to stop ngRouter from over-riding.

Then change `href=""` to `[attr.data-target]=""`

```
<span class="carousel-control-prev" [attr.data-target]="'#' + Car.id" role="button" data-slide="prev"></span>
```