# How to make Previous and next button of carousel working?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have two different part which i am repeating using *ngfor loop

[image]

For First Part Prev And Next are working but for second part prev and next button are changing the first part image only not second part.

Here is my Prev And Next Button code using which i am changing images using carousel:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center ">
                <span (click)="OnPrivClick()" class="targe prevDesable">
                    
                    <a href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev" class="removeline">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                      <div style="width: 60px;">
                            <div id="holderpre" style="font-size: 14px; color: #000000; text-align: center;">
                              <div id="maskpre"></div>
                              <div id="maskpre"></div>
                              <div id="mask"></div>
                              <i class="fa fa-arrow-left preiocon"></i>
                              <span class="prebutton">PREV</span>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                     </a>               
      </span>
                <span (click)="OnNextClick()" class="addcursor">        
        <a href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next" class="removeline">
                      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <div style="width: 133px;">
                            <div id="holder" style="font-size: 14px;color: #000000;text-align: center;">
                               <div id="mask2"></div>
                                <div id="mask1" style="position: absolute;bottom: -2px;left:0px;width:50%;height: 1px;background-color:#ffffff;border: 2px solid white">
                                </div>
                             <span class="buttcolor"> NEXT</span> &nbsp;
                             <i class="fa fa-arrow-right nexticon"></i>
                            </div>
          </div>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is Image Code:

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let space of xyz && xyz[i]; let j=index">
                    <div class="carousel-item active underlinecarosel" [ngClass]="{'active':j===0}">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12 col-sm-12">
                                <img [src]="xyz[i][j].attributes.document" class="d-block ">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </ng-container>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Can anyone help me where i am making mistake so that Second part's prev and next button will change only second part's image not first.

Any Lead would be helpful

Comment: You have #carouselExampleControls twice? Once per each carrousel?

Comment: No i have written only once.

Comment: Are you sure there's no ID's repeated? How do you differentiate between the two?

Comment: I am using ngFor loop. so based on content it will repeat itself. ID's are not repeated.

Comment: Show us the OnPrivClick() and OnNextClick(). What it seems it's happening is that your function sees somehow the first carrousel only. That's why I asked about the ID's.

Comment: i have written nothing on these functions.

Comment: Your question is confusing: " Second part's prev and next button will change only second part's image not first." so how does it change if the functions are empty?

Comment: taking id's reference. i want to know the idea how can i make id such that respective part button will change respective images

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58078183/multiple-bootstrap-carousel-single-page-dynamic-ids-via-ngfor-how-to-add-p

Comment: I'll check this one. Thanks for your time buddy. Much appreciated

Comment: No problem. Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521257/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-twitter-bootstrap-carousels-on-one-page